# The Sony Alpha A77M2 and the Camera Remote API

Tags: camera, sony

The new A77M2 has WiFi and the menus look like the camera having the Remote Camera API - and a Sony App for Android is working with the camera (but this app is just a bad joke).

I'd like to use the WiFi caps of the camera for some "live backup" (sending all images automatically to a notebook or (windows) tablet).

As I couldn't find an app or a software for doing that I took into consideration to write it on my own - shouldn't be too complicated as I'm in the software business (database and general C# programming).

But the docs in the SDK don't mention the A77M2 (but the A7s which was released after the A77M2 is mentioned so I think I've the latest version of the SDK).

So my questions are:

- is the A77M2 included?
- is it possible to do what I plan? (the camera must be controlled with their own dials and controls - only the image files should be transfered)
- or is their any software/app that does just what I want? (yes I Know those EyeFi cards and I have one and they are kind of nightmare....)

Thanks,
Achim

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know, A77M2 is not in the current list of devices supported by Camera Remote API beta SDK. Remote Camera Control Software by Sony [Link](http://www.sony-europe.com/support/en/content/cnt-dwnl/prd-dime/sony-remote-camera-control-ver33/SLT-A99#relevant_products) might come in handy for your situation.

Please check discussions at [http://community.sony.com/](http://community.sony.com/t5/Cameras-Camcorders/ct-p/digital-still-cameras-camcorders%20%22http://community.sony.com) for other solutions.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team at Sony

Comment: Well - what's Wi-Fi good for on the A77M2 if the camera is not supported by Sonys own SDK???? And why are there those menu entries "send to computer" etc.???

The RCC Software isn't a real solution requiring an usb cable between camera and computer.... Can you imagine such a setup somewhere outdoors in the streets??? As backup for your pictures when there is the risk of either falling into water or some nice people from some "services" requiring you to give them your cards???? Or more "peaceful" on a sports field or concert sending your photos to your assistant to send them to the newspaper?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late to answer. Anyway here is what happens with A77m2

1. There is WiFi API that is used by Sony's own remote control app
2. As you have seen the remote control app cannot do much with A77m2 because the APIs exposed by that camera and subsequent A99m2, A9 and A7m3 are severely degraded.

So you can actually download the Sample code posted by Sony with the SDK and start playing.

The operations you will have at your disposal are described in the SDK. Here is the A77m2 list of available operation so you can make your judgement if it is worth the effort:

["getMethodTypes","getAvailableApiList","setShootMode","getShootMode","getSupportedShootMode","getAvailableShootMode","setFlashMode","getFlashMode","getSupportedFlashMode","getAvailableFlashMode","setSelfTimer","getSelfTimer","getSupportedSelfTimer","getAvailableSelfTimer","startLiveview","stopLiveview","actTakePicture","startMovieRec","stopMovieRec","getApplicationInfo","getVersions","getEvent"]

All you can do is display live view, take picture, start video recording, change flash mode, work the self timer. That is all. You cannot set focus point or ask the camera to focus. You cannot zoom the live view. You cannot change any exposure settings. 95% of the meaningful API that is on all cameras from NEX-5R through A6500 is not there.

I also believe Sony are killing the whole thing now with A9 and A7m3 lacking meaningful wireless API. Sad.

Answer (score 0):

If the official "Smart Remote" is not providing sufficient functionality for your needs, you could consider writing on camera (Android) apps.

See:
https://github.com/ma1co/Sony-PMCA-RE

There are already a number of 'community' apps:
https://sony-pmca.appspot.com/apps